# How to get that when Frame Edge Touches another Frame Edge?

Tags: ios, cgrect, edge-detection, boundary

I have two rectangle as show below, both can rotate both can be resized.

[image]

[image]

Now my question is, whenever yellow will move towards white Rectangle which is before 5px, Green rect edge. I should be notified when yellow rect will touch the white rect lines.

After doing a lot of work I am able to do when the both rectangle is not rotated. For the same way when that view rotated I should be notified. I have draw the white rect in first image. Please consider the same image for rotated one.

Comment: I don't think this is/was very understandable, and can be closed (at this very late stage) as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score -1):

Just Try this I think It will work

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // use this to pass the 'touch' onward in case no subviews trigger the touch
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: i guess you did not get my problem.Your answer tell something else.